# Need first record based on the earliest date - Sql Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have the below data.

```
Base table
Id   DateTime
201  2015-05-03 08:01
301  2015-05-03 08:20
401  2015-05-03 08:40

Extract Table
Id   DateTime            Location
201  2015-05-03 07:50    City A
201  2015-05-03 08:01    City B
201  2015-05-03 08:50    City C
301  2015-05-03 07:15    City E
301  2015-05-03 08:01    City F
301  2015-05-03 08:20    City G
401  2015-05-03 08:40    City X
401  2015-05-03 08:55    City Y

Desired Result:
Location  Id    DateTime
City A    201   2015-05-03 07:50
City E    301   2015-05-03 07:15
City X    401   2015-05-03 08:40
```

To clear the picture, I am trying to get the first location for each customer where they checked in. Since I will be filtering some Locations I will need to have

```
WHERE Location in ('City A','City B','City C','City E','City F','City G','City X','City Y')
```

Thanks.

Comment: While it's great to use sql fiddle to illustrate your question, this question will be useless to future readers if that link ever goes dead.

Comment: Link is now working there was syntax error in column alias, can you please add your desire result ?

Comment: MySQL (fiddle) or SQL Server (tag)?

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  It is not clear to me (even with the SQL Fiddle) what you are trying to do.

Comment: It's SQL Server 2012. I am about to add the desired results. Thanks.

Comment: @TabAlleman - I will update the question so that it will be helpful for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still think a LEFT JOIN is the way to go:

```
SELECT extract.id, extract.location
FROM [base]
INNER JOIN [extract] ON [base].id = [extract].id
LEFT JOIN extract [earlierExtract] ON [extract].id = [earlierExtract].id
    AND [earlierExtract].DATETIME < [extract].DATETIME
    AND [earlierExtract].Location IN (
        'City A'
        ,'City B'
        ,'City C'
        ,'City E'
        ,'City F'
        ,'City G'
        ,'City X'
        ,'City Y'
        )
WHERE extract.Location IN (
        'City A'
        ,'City B'
        ,'City C'
        ,'City E'
        ,'City F'
        ,'City G'
        ,'City X'
        ,'City Y'
        )
    AND earlierextract.id IS NULL
```

Comment: This is getting really complicated. Let's make it simple. How can I get the first location for each id from Extract table based on the earliest date? I am trying to find out which location a customer was checked in at. Ignore if ADateTime does not match RDateTime.

Comment: That's what I did with b2 and b3. b2  joins extract records that match the id. b3 has records which match the id and have an earlier date. But since the WHERE clause sets those to NULL, then the query ends up only returning lines where b2 is the earliest record.There are other ways to do it.

Comment: I have updated my original question. Please have a look at it when you get time. Thanks.

Comment: I think this will solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18745459/how-to-get-the-first-row-form-sql-group-query

Comment: I updated my answer already, but that method you linked will also work. There are about 5 ways to do this.

Comment: Okay. Let's use LEFT JOIN. But, Id's need to match in Base table and I don't see your code using Base table. Also, let's include DateTime in select statement as well. Please look at my desired result in the original question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: ok just join it in then. One question though, do you want to show base table entries which have no extract entry?

Comment: Once I filter the customer type in Base table, all the Ids in Base table will be present in the Extract table as well. That's why I need Base table and that is to filter the customer types.

Comment: That worked. I am trying to understand your code now. Thank you so much.

Comment: Here's a tip for better understanding it. Comment out the   AND earlierextract.id IS NULL part for a moment, then add , * to your select to see all the fields. What you are doing then is returning every base table entry connected to every extract entry (the INNER JOIN), as well, if there are any other extract entries which have an earlier datetime for the same id, you are showing those beside it. So if an extract had 2 before it, it shows 2 times, if it was the first one it only shows once. Now what the filter does is only select those that are first.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
select b.id,
       (CASE WHEN b.ADateTime = e.RDateTime THEN e.Location
             ELSE (SELECT TOP 1 e.Location
                   FROM Extract e2
                   WHERE e2.id = e.id
                   ORDER BY RdateTime ASC
                  ) 
        END) AS [Test],
       a.Location
from Base b inner join
     Extract e 
     on b.id = e.id
where b.id = 301;
```

This gets the location associated with the minimum matching `id`.  There are definitely other ways to expression this logic, assuming this is what you are really looking for.

Comment: Gordon! I just updated my original question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get what you want utilizes a Windowed Aggregate Function, ROW_NUMBER:

```
select *
from
 (
   SELECT ...,
      ROW_NUMBER() -- assign a sequence, oldest row gets 1
      OVER (PARTITION BY e.id
            ORDER BY e.[DateTime]) as rn
   FROM [base] as b
   JOIN [extract] as e
     ON b.id = e.id
   WHERE Location in ('City A','City B','City C','City E','City F','City G','City X','City Y')
     AND ... -- any additional filter you need
 ) as dt
WHERE rn = 1 -- first join all rows, then return only the oldest.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to use an EXISTS, to bring back only the earliest record.

```
--Sample data population...
DECLARE @BaseTable TABLE (ID INT, DateTime SMALLDATETIME) 
DECLARE @ExtractTable TABLE (ID INT, DateTime SMALLDATETIME, Location VARCHAR(25))
INSERT INTO @BaseTable (ID, DateTime) SELECT 201, '2015-05-03 08:01'
INSERT INTO @BaseTable (ID, DateTime) SELECT 301, '2015-05-03 08:20'
INSERT INTO @BaseTable (ID, DateTime) SELECT 401, '2015-05-03 08:40'
INSERT INTO @ExtractTable (ID, DateTime, Location) SELECT 201, '2015-05-03 07:50', 'City A'
INSERT INTO @ExtractTable (ID, DateTime, Location) SELECT 201, '2015-05-03 08:01', 'City B'
INSERT INTO @ExtractTable (ID, DateTime, Location) SELECT 201, '2015-05-03 08:50', 'City C'
INSERT INTO @ExtractTable (ID, DateTime, Location) SELECT 301, '2015-05-03 07:15', 'City E'
INSERT INTO @ExtractTable (ID, DateTime, Location) SELECT 301, '2015-05-03 08:01', 'City F'
INSERT INTO @ExtractTable (ID, DateTime, Location) SELECT 401, '2015-05-03 08:40', 'City X'
INSERT INTO @ExtractTable (ID, DateTime, Location) SELECT 401, '2015-05-03 08:55', 'City Y'

--Example of lookup, using EXISTS to bring back the earliest check-in location of the customer...
SELECT
     ExtractTable.Location
    ,BaseTable.ID
    ,ExtractTable.DateTime
FROM @BaseTable BaseTable
INNER JOIN @ExtractTable ExtractTable ON
        EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1
                FROM @ExtractTable Ext
                WHERE Ext.ID=BaseTable.ID
                GROUP BY Ext.ID
                HAVING MIN(Ext.DateTime)=ExtractTable.DateTime
            )
WHERE ExtractTable.Location IN 
    (
         'City A'
        ,'City B'
        ,'City C'
        ,'City E'
        ,'City F'
        ,'City G'
        ,'City X'
        ,'City Y'
    )
```

I think you'll find this much much more manageable than the existing solutions.

Comment: NOTE: This solution does make the assumption that a person cannot be checked into multiple locations at the same moment. The data structure provided seems overly-simplified, so I was a little limited on available field to use. In more realistic scenarios, there would likely be additional fields, like maybe an ID of the check-in, which could have been evaluated in addition to (or possible instead of) the check-in date/time value. This should be good enough to get most people started down the right path, though!